# how to rotate a view from left to right using CATransform3DMakeRotation

Tags: iphone, ios, calayer, catransform3d

I know how to rotate a view from right to left

```
CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
transform.m34 = 0.0015;
view.layer.transform = transform;
```

But i cant rotate it from left to right.
Please help me.

Comment: Try this: transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

Comment: This will rotate upside down, and i want a page fold animation. Like opening a book(right to left rotation) and closing a book (left to right).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by “left to right” and “right to left”.  Anyway, as you have discovered, you can't control the direction of the animation just by setting the transform matrix, because both -M_PI and +M_PI have the same final effect, so there's no way for Core Animation to reliably know which way you want it to rotate.

Instead, [you can animate the `transform.rotation.y` key path of the layer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coreanimation_guide/Key-ValueCodingExtensions/Key-ValueCodingExtensions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH12-SW1).  This is a little more complicated to do, particularly since you want to animate a view's layer instead of a freestanding layer (not controlled by a view).

Anyway, here's the code I tested:

```
- (IBAction)rotateButtonWasTapped:(id)sender {
    // Establish the perspective to be used during the animation.
    CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
    transform.m34 = 0.0015;
    self.imageView.layer.transform = transform;

    static CGFloat kAngle = -M_PI;

    [CATransaction begin]; {
        // After the animation completes, make the transform “permanent”.  Otherwise it
        // will be undone when the animation is removed from the layer.
        [CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
            self.imageView.layer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, kAngle, 0, 1, 0);
        }];

        // Animate the rotation using Core Animation's extension to Key Value Coding.
        // The sign of kAngle determines the direction of rotation.
        CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation
            animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.y"];
        animation.fromValue = @0;
        animation.toValue = @(kAngle);
        animation.duration = 1;
        [self.imageView.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:animation.keyPath];
    } [CATransaction commit];
}
```

This rotates the view such that the left edge of the view moves “closer” to the user during the rotation.  If that's not what you mean by “left to right”, change the definition of `kAngle` to `M_PI` and it will rotate in the other direction.  I have tested both ways.  You can even spin the layer multiple times in one animation.  For example, try defining `kAngle` as `-3 * M_PI`.

Comment: Hi Rob thanks for the help, your code is working. "Left to Right" means when a view rotates from left direction (like closing a book). And animation.fromValue should be 0 instead of @0 and toValue should be [NSNumber numberWithFloat:-kAngle];, am i right ?

Comment: Both fromValue and toValue must be objects. @0 is an NSNumber representing zero, but just plain 0 is a null pointer.

Answer (score 0):

I did not find anything in the function documentation, but I think you can just make the rotation angle negative to rotate into the other direction.

Comment: CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI, 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f) is giving same rotation i.e right to left.

Comment: @ViratNaithani try CATransform3DMakeRotation(-M_PI, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

Comment: @ViratNaithani maybe you need 2 steps: first to (-M_PI_2, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f) and the last (0, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

Comment: @TonyMkenu The combination of the above 2 rotation transformation is giving left to right rotation. But First transformation Rotation is not clean at the end.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to rotate the view, back to the initial position... just do it with:

```
transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(0, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f)
```

or you can "combine" more..

```
CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(-M_PI_2, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(0, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
transform.m34 = 0.0015;
view.layer.transform = transform;
```

You can try... to use `CATransform3D transform = starLayer.transform;` instead of `CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DIdentity;`

Comment: I sow that you already accepted another answer.. and is ok, is a nice "piece of code" :) +1 for that answer.. Just for curiosity, my code (above) in not working how you desired?

Answer (score 0):

-(void)updateTimer
{
    if(update<125)
    update=update+1;

```
NSTimeInterval now = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
NSTimeInterval interval = now - start;
int inter = (int)(interval*update);
inter*=10;

milliSec = (inter) % 1000;
seconds = (inter/1000) % 60;
minutes = (inter/60000) % 60;

timeValue = oldTimeValue+inter;

// Set Digital clock

// Set Analog clock hands

secHand.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation (Degrees2Radians(-(timeValue%1000)*360/1000), 0, 0, 1);
```

}